# Can bisection method find complex roots?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, nonlinear-system, bisection

Intuitively, I don't think that the bisection method can locate complex roots due to its use of intervals, midpoints and sign of f(a),f(b) and f(c).

However, I am not sure about this claim. Can anyone please explain this in detail?

Comment: The bisection method can't find complex roots, because complex roots lie in a plane.  If you take two points in the plane  and neither is a root, there's no reason to believe that a root lies on the line segment joining them.

Comment: [Multivariate Bisection Method](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05542.pdf).